# How to search for (static) C function definitions in Xcode?

Tags: xcode

I have a few C functions in various implementation files (.m) that should be labelled as `static` but are not. How do I find them quickly, easily, and simply?

Due to what I assume is the liberalness of LLVM, not all of these functions are declared either. This makes the task a bit harder.

The Xcode Navigator (lefthand) pane, has a Symbol Navigator tab, but this only displays symbols declared in the `@interface`.

In the Search Navigator tab, I changed the *Style* field to "Regular Expression" and used `[a-zA-Z]\(`. This is too broad a search. For example, `@selector(` is found also. But it was enough for me to manually pick thru all the hits and accomplish my task.

In Terminal, I can do `awk '/[a-zA-Z]\(.*[^;]$/' *.m` (that regular expression does not work as expected in Search Navigator) and my unwanted hits are much fewer, but I would prefer an Xcode-only solution.

I have already solved my problem, but I am asking this question because someone else who knows Xcode better than I may have a better solution, and I do not see a similar question.

Answer (score 0):

What does "should be labeled static" mean?  Is it the same as "could be labeled static because they are unused outside the compilation unit"?  If so, one could use 'nm' to get the symbols out of the .o files then figure out which them were only used in a single .m file.  That would satisfy the 'simply, easily, quickly' goal, once the script was written.  :¬)